# Update gtalk status programmatically?

Tags: gmail

How can I update my gmail status programmatically?

Comment: Do you have a Gtalk API somewhere or a library that can talk to the Gtalk server?

Comment: Any language will do (python preferred). I don't need source code, API is enough if you can link to it.

Comment: I found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473487/how-do-i-set-a-jabber-status-with-python-xmpp which answers my question. The only problem left is that gtalk client in gmail doesn't see the updates (other accounts do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTalk uses an xmpp based protocol, you can find libraries which implement the protocol and do what you want to do. You might also want to look at http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3922.html, in particular at the  tag. The xmpp server you want is talk.google.com port 5222. http://code.google.com/apis/talk/open_communications.html has more general information.